# How can I know when a Rodio source or sink is done?

Tags: rust, rodio

I'm trying to play some sounds with [rodio](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.11.0/rodio/index.html).

I am creating a `Source` and putting it into a `Sink`, but how can I know when one or the other has stopped playing? For example, I want to move to the next song after the first.

```
let device = rodio::default_output_device().unwrap();
let sink = Sink::new(&device);
let file = File::open(path).unwrap();
let source = rodio::Decoder::new(BufReader::new(file)).unwrap();
sink.append(source);
```

I have found nothing in the rodio docs about a callback or something similar. There is a [`Done` struct](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.11.0/rodio/source/struct.Done.html), but it's not clear to me how to use it, or even if is the thing I'm looking for.

Comment: `Sink` has [`Sink::empty`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.11.0/rodio/struct.Sink.html#method.empty). [`Sink::sleep_until_end`](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.11.0/rodio/struct.Sink.html#method.sleep_until_end) might also work depending on your usecase.

Comment: sleep_until_end blocks the thread, so does not seem a good idea.
Sink::empty means I have to poll that variable until it's true ? :-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `Sink::done` which [returns `true` if there are no more samples within the sink to play](https://docs.rs/rodio/0.14.0/rodio/struct.Sink.html#method.empty).